# How to pass Multiple Values in a Solidity Event

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, javascript, events

I am emitting within a function the following in a solidity smart contract.

```
emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId)
```

In my front-end JavaScript code, I am reading the values as follows:

```
let transfer = receipt.events.Transfer.returnValues.tokenId
```

If I declare my event using only the tokenId parameter (as below) in my smart contract, I am receiving the values of all three parameters in my front-end and everything works properly.

```
event Transfer(uint256 tokenId);
```

However, if I declare the event as follows with the three parameters, following the standard practice, I am no longer receiving any values and it no longer works!

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 tokenId);
```

What am I missing?

Thank you. J

Comment: Can you see if the event is getting emitted?

Comment: The compilation should generate a new ABI with proper definitions. Perhaps the frontend is using and old ABI without the new event, or it is using the address of the previous contract without the new event.

Comment: @Ismael, yes, I am using the proper ABI.

Comment: Thank you @hrkrshnn. When I use only the tokenId param within my declaration of the event, I am actually receiving all three values emitted by the event (i.e. returnValues with the "from", "to" and "tokenId" fields.) When I use the 3 parameters for the event declaration, I obtain the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValues' of undefined

Comment: I was able to make it work properly using the following: event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId); Instead of: event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 tokenId);